# How can I mount a thumbdrive to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, terminal, external-disk, jailbreak, mount

I have a jailbroken iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.3. I'd like to be able to connect a r/w thumbdrive to my phone, but I don't know what kind of adapter I'd have to buy/make. Does anyone have any suggestions how to do this?

I'll likely be able to mount it in a terminal GUI (NewTerm2 in this case) using `fdisk` and then `mount`, but if needed I can install other commands.

Lightning<-->USB (a)

Comment: do an internet search for iphone flash drive, there are lots of these out there. The just plug into the lightning port. Many also have a USB jack on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

SanDisk already make the iXpand thumbdrive series from small to damned big, which have USB 2-3 and lightning connectors on them from the manufacturer.

I use one routinely without issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking to be able to mount any thumb drive (therefor via an adapter), instead of a specific one